# Why won't each color fill its respective box in my menu bar?

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

My end goal is when each box is clicked, the background-color is shown. When I added the Javascript for this, it became apparent that the back-ground color didn't actually fill the whole box. This wasn't apparent when there wasn't a color. How do I fix this?

http://jsfiddle.net/k7rm33h7/

HTML:

```
    <div id="logo">Codeplayer</div>

    <ul class="toggle">

        <li id="htmlLi">HTML</li>
        <li id="cssLi">CSS</li>
        <li id="jsLi">JS</li>
        <li id="resultLi">Result</li>

    </ul>

        <button>Run</button>


</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* ----------- UNIVERSAL -----------*/

    a, body, html, ul, li, div, button {

        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none; 
        font-family: helvetica; 
    }

    #logo, .toggle {
        line-height: 50px; 
    }



/* ----------- MENU BAR -----------*/

    #menu {
        background-color: #EDEBED; 
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px; 
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
        position: absolute;


    }

/* ----------- LOGO -----------*/

    #logo {
        float: left;
        font-weight: bold; 
        margin-left: 15px; 
        font-size: 20px; 
        height: 20px;
        text-shadow: 1px 2px #000000; 
        color: #9d9d9a;
    }


/* ----------- TOGGLE BAR -----------*/

    .toggle li {
        list-style: none;
        float: left; 
        margin-left: 20px; 
        border-right: 1px solid black;  
        padding-right: 17px; 
        font-weight: bold; 
    }

    .toggle {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 300px; 
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px; 
        margin-top: 10px; 
        border: 1px solid black;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;
        border-radius: 4px; 


    }

/* ----------- TOGGLE LIST ITEMS -----------*/

    #resultLi {
        border-right: none;
    }


/* ----------- BUTTON -----------*/

    button {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 15px; 
        height: 30px; 
        width: 50px; 
        position: relative;
        top: -30px;
        border-radius: 4px; 

    }

/* ----------- TEST -----------*/



    #htmlLi {
        background-color: red; 
    }

    #cssLi {
        background-color: green; 
    }

    #jsLi {
        background-color: yellow; 
    }

    #resultLi {
        background-color: blue; 
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `padding-left` on your `li`s, instead of `margin-left`.

```
.toggle li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 20px; /* <-- padding-left */
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    padding-right: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This is because the `background-color` of an element does not extend *outside* of the containing box. Think of `margin` as creating *external* whitespace and `padding` as creating *internal* whitespace.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you! 

I have a follow up, if you don't mind. If I wanted to target a specific li within .toggle when I click and have its background color change, do I have to create a jQuery command for each box, or is there a way to detect which thing I've clicked? Meaning, is there a $(this) type command that applies to the item you've clicked, or will I need to make a $("xxxx").click( function()) for each box in .toggle?

Comment: `$('.toggle li').click(function () {  var clickedElement = $(this); });` Inside the click handler function you can use `$(this)` to reference the element that triggered the event.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just removing the `margin` and `padding`, then set a fixed width and center the contents. Much easier to manage in my opinion and will work fine since your container is fixed @ `300px`. I also added CSS to remove border from `last-child` since it's not needed.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7rm33h7/1/)**

```
.toggle li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 74.2px; //fixed width allows you to center text exactly
    border-right: 1px solid black;   
    font-weight: bold; 
    text-align: center; //easy as pie
}
.toggle li:last-child {
    border: none;
}
```